# Rails file Remains Cached on Production - Some of the Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem that only occurs on my production box. Works fine in DEV and TEST environments. The problem is the page that is served up is cached - doesnt reflect recent changes I have made. The odd part is it doesnt happen all the time. If I clear the browser cache it might work until I close out the browser and then open and reload the app - then it fails again. Sometimes I can load the page fine in IE, Chrome and Firefox. But if I close out Firefox and open it again- it can then fail with the old page.
Not sure if it matters, but the file I am trying to change is a haml file.
Here is what I have tried so far:

On the production box itself:

```
 rm -rm tmp/cache/assets

 rake assets:clobber
 rake assets:precompile
 rake assets:clean
 rake tmp:cache:clear
 rails tmp:clear
 rails restart
```

After 'rails restart' it seems to work for a little while. Again, works in all browsers until I close out Firefox a few times...then reverts back to the old file. Also worked fine for a couple of open/close of Chrome - then reverted to old file.
I found another issue here where someone set no-cache.
In application_controller.rb

```
 before_filter :set_cache_buster

 def set_cache_buster
     response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store"
     response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
     response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
 end
```

In config/environments/production.rb:

```
 config.cache_classes = false
 config.cache_store = false
 config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

If I try to run 'Rails.cache.clear' from the console I get:

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method 'clear' for false:FalseClass
```

This is a very odd issue. Anyone think of any other things I could try?

Comment: What is your production environment like? Do you have multiple production instances, each with their own files?

Comment: You're getting `NoMethodError` because `Rails.cache` is an accessor to get the cache_store object. You turned it off with `config.cache_store = false`. [That cache store is separate from SQL and Page caching](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores).

Comment: You say everything works fine when you restart rails, it doesn't look like a cache problem (it would cache the working view). Try stop > start instead of restart and check if that fixed. Also, what app server are you using? puma? maybe when you try to restart it it's not properly stopping the old workers and some stay mixed with the new ones? check puma logs for errors or somehing.

Comment: Schwern... only one production instance with its own files. I'll try turning back on cache_store. thanks!

Comment: arieljuod.. just found out we dont use the rails server in prod. we use passenger and apache to serve up the files.

Comment: I tried 'passenger-config restart-app' but that didnt do it either

Comment: @Schwern... turns out you were right! We checked our AWS settings and someone had setup a seperate load balancer with the old code. So it was occasionally hitting the old stuff. When I turned off the 2nd load balancer all is well. If you post this as an answer I will accept it!! thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your production environment is in the cloud there is no guarantee about the state of the filesystem or how many instances will be running, unless you specifically set it up that way. One request might go to instance A while the next request might go to instance B. Each instance has its own filesystem and cache.

Furthermore, cloud instances are regularly moved around and you will lose your cache.

Instead of caching on the filesystem, you'll need to use a cache server such as [memcached](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-memcachestore) or [Redis](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-rediscachestore). Or make your production environment run on a single server, but that does not scale.